# How to extract planes precisely from the point cloud?

Tags: point-clouds, ransac, pcl

I used RANSAC to extract planes from the point cloud iteratively, but the intersection of two planes is always wrongly labeled.
[Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jQUCP.png),
The blue part and the green part are two perpendicular planes extracted by RANSAC. Obviously, the blue one is first extracted, but it also includes the points on the green plane. These points do satisfy the equation of the blue plane, but they are not within the range of the blue plane. Though the point normal can be checked to tell if the specific point is labeled rightly, this will have much more computational cost. So does anybody know some better solutions which can solve this problem?

I have thought about it for a long time and feel there is no good solution. I don’t know if there are any related papers that can propose a good solution.

Comment: The problem is that points of the green area are counted to the blue area? What is the problem with your current approach? The runtime is too long? How big are the point clouds? Can you work with reduced data (e.g. VoxelGrid)? Another possibility would be to delete points that satisfy both plane equations.